# Flutter firestore query documents by date as the heading

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase firestore to store data in collection documents for my flutter application. Each document is having it's timestamp. I want to show date as the heading for data that was stored in same day but I have no idea how to do it. The code below is fetching all the documents but I don't know how to group them with date as the heading for documents created in the same date. Any help please?

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('chatrooms')
                  .doc(chatRoomId)
                  .collection('chats')
                  .orderBy('time', descending: false)
                  .snapshots(),
```

Answer (score 0):

To group the documents by date, you'd do something like this in pseudo-code:

```
String currentDate = "";
for each document in your query snapshot {
  get the time from the document snapshot
  convert the time to a string in format yyyy-mm-dd
  if (timeString != currentDate) {
    output a group header for timeString
  }
  ... other things you want to do with the document
  currentDate = timeString
}
```

Comment: What does currentDate represent?

Comment: It represents the current data, the value you are grouping on. For example: it'd be `2021-12-19` if you were on a document of today, and then become `2021-12-20` once you encounter the first document for tomorrow.